# Delphi 2006 - What's the best way to gracefully kill a thread and still have the OnTerminate handler fire?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, terminate, delphi-2006

I have a thread that sometimes freezes (I suspect) due to a DLL call that never returns.  In the general case, where you have calls to blocking routines like Indy, is there a way of recovering from this in such a way that the thread OnTerminate handler fires?  Will this happen if I call TerminateThread?

Comment: Sounds more like good old fashioned deadlock, could easily be your threading code to blame

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TerminateThread()` is an immediate brute-force termination. It will NOT let the `OnTerminaate` event fire. The only way `OnTerminate` can fire is if the thread's `Execute()` method exits through normal means, whether that be gracefully or by raising an uncaught exception (which will set the thread's `FatalExpection` property).

In the case of Indy specifically, a blocking socket operation can be aborted by disconnecting the socket from the context of another thread.  That is not usually possible with blocking DLL functions, unless they expose that kind of functionality in their API.

Comment: Is that really ' **for** the context of another thread'? Or did you mean ' **from** the context of another thread'? If you did mean "for" is TIdContext involved and how would you go about doing it?